# Object destructuring assignment with default value of itself

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

I need to destruct an object that some of the variables may already have a value.

```js
let foo = 1, bar, baz = 'Hello';

const config = { foo: 42 };

({ foo, bar, baz } = config);

console.log({ foo, bar, baz });
```

This gives me

```json
{
  "foo": 42,
  "bar": undefined,
  "baz": undefined
}
```

But what I really want is

```json
{
  "foo": 42,
  "bar": undefined,
  "baz": "Hello"
}
```

I want to rewrite the value if there is a value with a same name in `config`, if there's not, use its original value instead.

I can't assign default value while destructuring since the values are assigned previously.

```js
({ foo = 1, bar, baz = 'Hello' } = config);
```

I know I can assign it like this but it's too clunky since there are more than 20 variables.

```js
({ foo = foo, bar = bar, baz = baz } = config);
```

Is there a better way to write it without repeating `x = x` all the time?

Comment: The fact that you have so many standalone variables is a smell. Since it sounds like they're all pretty related - they may be present in `config` - if I were you, consider if you could keep them consolidated in just a single object, it'll let you keep the code a lot more DRY (at least in this section). Once the final object is constructed, *then* destructure later if you need to, IMO

Comment: @CertainPerformance I was trying to do that but it's hard to refactor without breaking anything since the values are used everywhere so I gave up eventually. But I absolutely agree with you, it's quite conter-productive this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an object with the original values (the defaults), and spread the `config` into it, overriding the default values, and then destructure it:

```js
let foo = 1, bar, baz = 'Hello';

const config = { foo: 42 };

({ foo, bar, baz } = { foo, bar, baz, ...config });

console.log({ foo, bar, baz });
```

Answer (score 1):

`Object.assign` would be a great candidate to resolve your problem. Good luck ^^!

```js
let foo = 1, bar, baz = 'Hello';

const config = { foo: 42 };
const target = {foo, bar, baz};
const source = ({ foo, host, bar } = config);

const result = Object.assign(target, source);
console.log(result);
```

---

In case you want to **re-assign the variables instead of returning a new object**, you can do like below.

```js
let foo = 1, bar, baz = 'Hello';
const config = { foo: 42 };

// Step 1: merge 2 objects
const mergedObject = { foo, bar, baz, ...config };

// Step 2: re-assign variables from `mergedObject`
({foo, bar, baz} = mergedObject);

console.log({foo, bar, baz});
```

Comment: @Hao Wu I've just updated my answer with `using spread`, pls take a look at ^^!

Comment: But what I wanted is to rewrite the variables but not to create an object... If you console log `foo` after it, it's still remain unchanged.

Comment: @HaoWu Oops, I misunderstood. I've just updated my answer. Pls, take a look at it once again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop `config` then assign value like this.

```js
let foo = 1, bar, baz = 'Hello';
const config = { foo: 42 };
const result = {foo, bar, baz};

Object.entries(config).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if(result[key])
    result[key] = value;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It's the same as `console.log({ foo, bar, baz, ...config });` with one line ^^!

Comment: I need to change the variables `foo`, `bar` and `baz` which defined with `let`, this only changes the properties of the `result` object :(